# term for the finalizing dialogue used when ending phone conversation

Tags: terminology

How do you term the finalizing dialogue used when ending a phone conversation.Particularly with a loved one like a close immediate family member,Partener &/or offspring.

Comment: Thanks Guys..Sometimes answers can be right in front of our eyes,Occasiionally you just need a friend to help you focus")

Comment: Apologies..Writing on a (occasionally not so) smartphone keyboard..

Answer (score 1):

A *signoff* is typically the last recognizable key-phrase in communication.

For informal communication with close family, "*saying your [cherished] goodbyes*" might be a better fit.